# How to backup a RDS database in AWS using terraform but not destroying it after each apply

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, cloud, devops, amazon-rds

I want to have automatic backups in my RDS database using terraform. I have done this already:

`

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "main" {

    snapshot_identifier = data.aws_db_snapshot.from[0].id
    identifier          = "${local.prefix}-db"
    storage_type = "gp2"
    instance_class       = "db.t2.micro"
    db_subnet_group_name = aws_db_subnet_group.main.name
    backup_retention_period = 7
    multi_az                = false
    skip_final_snapshot     = true
    vpc_security_group_ids  = [aws_security_group.rds.id]

    tags = merge(
        local.common_tags,
        tomap({ "Name" = "${local.prefix}-main" })
  )
}

data "aws_db_snapshot" "from" {

    count                  = length("test-dev-db") > 0 ? 1 : 0
    most_recent            = true
    db_instance_identifier = "test-db"

}
```

`

The problem for this is that in every apply I do, database is deleted and created again. So how can I avoid this?

Thanks

Comment: What is the plan output? What exactly causes its replacement?

Comment: Well, it seems that every time you run apply the data source is recreated and as per documentation https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/db_instance#snapshot_identifier this parameter tells the DB to be recreated from the snapshot.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Folks, I've already fixed this using this:

```
        lifecycle {
        ignore_changes = [snapshot_identifier]
        }
```

Using this meta-argument it works for me. I took it from here:
https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).